# Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает этот код ( не могу понять что происходит после начала первого цикла for) :

Tags: python, булева-алгебра

```
from itertools import product, permutations


def f1(x, y, z, w):
    return (x <= y) or ((not w) == z)


def f2(x, y, z, w):
    return (x <= y) == (w and not z)


for a, b, c, d, e, f in product([0, 2], repeat=6):
    table = [(a, b, c, 0), (d, e, 0, 0), (f, 0, 0, 0)]
    if len(table) != len(set(table)):
        continue
    for p in permutations('xyzw'):
        if [f1(**dict(zip(p, r))) for r in table] == [f2(**dict(zip(p, r))) for r in table]:
            print(*p)
```

Насколько я понял, в коде задана таблица и он сам перебирает все значения которые могут в ней быть, в результате выводит верный ответ к этой задаче: [image]

Comment: А что он в принципе должен делать? Код сложный и без понимания темы уяснить суть его работы непросто.

Comment: Судя по всему, это код для решения второй задачи из ЕГЭ по информатике. Но тут что-то явно перемудренно

Comment: Я не могу разобраться какие значения перебирает переменная r в цикле for r in table

Comment: Этот код мягко говоря ужасен, пока вы его пишите, вы бы могли решить следующее задание, лучше использовать другой(в ответах)

Comment: За такой код в проме канделябром надо )  Код должен быть понятным, а тут нужно сидеть думать над каждой отдельной конструкцией, что же тут происходит. В промышленном программировании так не пишут, так только по приколу можно писать.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью циклов

```
print('x y z w')
for x in range(2):  # x может быть [0; 2)
    for y in range(2):  # y может быть [0; 2)
        for z in range(2):  # z может быть [0; 2)
            for w in range(2):  # w может быть [0; 2)
                # благодаря всем циклам мы переберём все варианты
                # записываем чему равны наши функции
                f1 = (x <= y) or (not w == z)
                f2 = (x <= y) == (w and not z)
                # если значения равны
                if f1 == f2:
                    print(x, y, z, w)
```

С помощью `itertools`

```
from itertools import product

print('x y z w')
# аналогично перебираем все варианты, сначала
# x:0,y:0,z:0,w:0, потом x:0,y:0,z:0,w:1 и т.д.
for x, y, z, w in product([0, 1], repeat=4):
    # записываем чему равны наши функции
    f1 = (x <= y) or (not w == z)
    f2 = (x <= y) == (w and not z)
    # если значения равны
    if f1 == f2:
        print(x, y, z, w)
```

Вывод:

```
x y z w
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 # можно вычеркнуть, т.к. не подходит по таблице
1 1 0 1
```

Ну, и несложная игра в Шерлока Холмса, что куда подходит (лучше смотреть по 0, что куда подходит в таблицу)

[image: ответ]

Comment: Могу порекомендовать видео, где хорошо объяснили это задание: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKBEN8-KfbM

Comment: Да, вообще это задание вполне себе легко решается и без питона, вручную.